# how android use BlueTooth printer print the WebView content

Tags: android, html, printing, bluetooth

how to print the HTML using a bluetooth printer with android?Can I print the String="< html > < body >You scored 192 points." into html page?

Comment: You can easily print the whole html page as a string. But if you want to preserve the format of the html page, i.e., the indents, then you have to take care of it manually when printing.

Comment: I want to print the html page,how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

There's a quick how-to on the Android Developer site about printing the contents of a WebView:

from https://developer.android.com/training/printing/html-docs.html

```
// Get a PrintManager instance
PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) getActivity()
        .getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);

// Get a print adapter instance
PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter = webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter();

// Create a print job with name and adapter instance
String jobName = getString(R.string.app_name) + " Document";
PrintJob printJob = printManager.print(jobName, printAdapter,
        new PrintAttributes.Builder().build());
```

You don't even have to display the WebView first - in fact they recommend that you use a dedicated invisible WebView for printing.

In order to print to a Bluetooth printer though, you'll need to have the print service app for that printer installed, or use a manufacturer-specific SDK - either of which might not exist :(

Comment: Please include the relevant information from the included link in your answer